# make UIScrollview scroll further then its contentSize

Tags: swift

I have a `UIScrollview` in my app. Then there's programmatically created content inside of that `scrollview`.

Now, is it possible to make my `UIScrollview` scroll e.g. `45px` more to the right then the actual content stretches without dodgy doing something like placing a transparent `UIView` inside of it?

Thanks :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by adding this 45 points in the the trailing/right constraint's constant of the last item that you add to the scrollView

Answer (score 0):

Add Insets to left of your **scrollView**:

```
scrollView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 0, bottom: 0, right: 45)
```

It sets the distance of the inset between the content view and the enclosing scroll view. The scroll view encloses the content view + content insets(Provided in each direction).